# Does ES6 Symbol guarantee 100% a unique identifier?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to know if the use of `Symbol()` guarantees 100% the creation of a unique token or the probability of clashing is almost zero. For example Git creates hash commits; the probability of creating duplicate hash commits is practical zero but not zero. Is that the case with `Symbol()`?

Comment: I fail to see how this could be an issue with git. git doesn't run your code. Could you expand on how you're using Symbol with git?

Comment: if your question yields to a different, than the unique characteristic, then i could reopen the question.

Comment: Git was just an example. Nothing to do with Symbol()

Comment: However, you did not get my point. My question is simple: Is the probability 0 or near zero?

Comment: it is zero, according to [ECMA 262 v 9.0](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type): *"Each possible Symbol value is unique and immutable."*

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are guaranteed to be unique. Even if we create many symbols with the same description, they are different values. The description is just a label that doesn’t affect anything.